# parsing complex json in flutterr

Tags: flutter

In my code I have to parse json. First link works right way, but the second invoke error 
Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'. 
How i can fix it and dive in this theme? What have I read about this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Map data;
  List userData;

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
//        "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=cf49c08b444ff4cb9e4d126b7e9f7513ba1ee58de7906e4360afc1a33d1bf4c0"
        );
    data = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      userData = data["data"];
    });
    debugPrint(data.toString());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Fake Friends"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to create a model for the object you want to parse and write the `fromJson()` and `toJson()` functions to control the parsing process.

There is a simple way to pass through this, just pass an example of the `Json object` you want to parse [here](https://jsontodart.com/) and it will generates you the classes you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `Map data;` as your type for the variable that receives the JSON, I can imagine that a payload is a list of multiple payloads and this is why it's giving you an error. Ideally y as suggested in another answer you want to create a Model for de data.